# Paint-like a pp on Unity too slow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, paint

I've been trying to create a Paint-like app through Unity for some kids and it's almost fine. The issue is that if you drag the finger too fast it will lag a bit and the lines will be straight and jagged. Any suggestions on how to improve it?

Basically, it works in the following way: the player can choose which color he wants to use and he can switch through a pencil and an eraser. When the player will drag his mouse/finger across the screen, the code will change the pixels of the image to which its assigned.

```
public class PaintColor : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IDragHandler
{

[SerializeField] ColorManager manager; //manages whether the player can draw and with what color

Vector2 prevPos;
Image sr;
[SerializeField] int brushWidth = 10;
[SerializeField] float maxDistance = 5; //when dragging, max possible distance between previous stored position and current

void Start()
{

    sr = GetComponent<Image>();
    ClearPanel();
}

/*get pixel coordinates from mouse position*/
Vector2 PixelPos(Vector2 v)
{


    var rt = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    int px = Mathf.Clamp(0, (int)(((v.x - rt.rect.x) * sr.sprite.texture.width) / rt.rect.width), sr.sprite.texture.width);
    int py = Mathf.Clamp(0, (int)(((v.y - rt.rect.y) * sr.sprite.texture.height) / rt.rect.height), sr.sprite.texture.height);

    return new Vector2(px, py);
}

public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{

    if (manager.CanColor())
    {

        Vector2 pixelPos;
        if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(GetComponent<RectTransform>(), eventData.position, eventData.pressEventCamera, out pixelPos))
            Draw(PixelPos(pixelPos));
        prevPos = pixelPos;
    }
}

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{

    if (manager.CanColor())
    {

        Vector2 pixelPos;
        if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(GetComponent<RectTransform>(), eventData.position, eventData.pressEventCamera, out pixelPos))
        {

            var distance = Mathf.Max(Vector2.Distance(prevPos, pixelPos), maxDistance);
            for (float lerp = 0; lerp <= 1; lerp += 1 / distance)    //color all pixels in between last recorded position and current
            {

                Draw(PixelPos(Vector2.Lerp(prevPos, pixelPos, lerp)));
            }
        }
        prevPos = pixelPos;
    }
}

/*clear out drawing panel*/
public void ClearPanel()
{

    var clear = new Color[(int)sr.sprite.rect.width * (int)sr.sprite.rect.height];
    for (int x = 0; x < clear.Length; x++)
        clear[x] = Color.clear;
    sr.sprite.texture.SetPixels(clear);
    sr.sprite.texture.Apply();
}

void Draw(Vector2 pixelPos)
{

    /*color pixels in area around pointer position*/
    for (int i = (int)pixelPos.x - brushWidth / 2; i < (int)pixelPos.x + brushWidth / 2; i++)
    {

        for (int j = (int)pixelPos.y - brushWidth / 2; j < (int)pixelPos.y + brushWidth / 2; j++)
        {

            sr.sprite.texture.SetPixel(i, j, manager.GetSelectedColor());
        }
    }
    sr.sprite.texture.Apply();
}
```

}

Comment: Did you check the profiler where exactly the slowdown is? Also from <https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixel.html>: *"SetPixel might be slower than some other texture methods because it converts the Color struct into the format the texture uses. To set pixel data more quickly, use SetPixelData instead."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a result of poor performance. You should run a profiler to identify the reason for the poor performance, but I'm going to make a guess:

```
sr.sprite.texture.SetPixel(i, j, manager.GetSelectedColor());
...
sr.sprite.texture.Apply();
```

Setting individual pixels is likely a slow operation, and may involve getting locks, etc. And you run "Apply" for each pixel, uploading the entire texture to the GPU for each modified pixel.

I have not used Unity enough to suggest the most appropriate solution. In most regular UI frameworks you would have a simple Draw Line method you could call. But I would at the very least fix the code to only call `Apply()` **once** per drag event, and you may consider using `GetPixelData` to get direct access to the texture memory. But I would try to find some more suitable methods for drawing lines, and if nothing more suitable exist, maybe consider some other framework?

Comment: Ok, I've fixed Apply as you said and it actually resolved the issue. I think I'll keep on using SetPixel because it seems simpler to set the color that way, but other than that thank you very much for pointing that out!